# How do I show that $ \mathrm{Tr}(\rho c_n^\dagger c_m) = \lambda_n \delta_{nm}$ implies that $\rho = \bigotimes_n \rho_n$?

Tags: fermions, density-operator, many-body

Consider a many-body system with a set of $N$ fermionic modes $\{ c_n \}$ which obey the algebra

$$ \{ c_n,c_m^\dagger \} = \delta_{nm}, \quad \{ c_n,c_m \} = \{ c_n^\dagger,c_m^\dagger \} = 0.$$

In [this review](https://arxiv.org/abs/0906.1499), in Eqs. (22) and (23), it says that if the system is in the state $\rho$ such that

$$ \mathrm{Tr}(\rho c^\dagger_n c_m ) = \lambda_n \delta_{nm},$$

then $\rho$ decomposes as $\rho = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2 \otimes \ldots \otimes \rho_N$, where $\rho_i$ is the density matrix of the $i$th mode. I have been trying to show this for myself.

### My attempt

Let us consider a simple case where we just have two fermions, $c_0$ and $c_1$. These two modes generate a four-dimensional Hilbert space, with a representation

$$ c^\dagger_0 = \sigma^+ \otimes \mathbb{I}, \quad c^\dagger_1 = \sigma^z \otimes \sigma^+$$

which indeed furnishes a representation of the fermionic algebra above, where $\sigma^i$ are the Pauli matrices and $\sigma^\pm = (\sigma^x \pm i \sigma^y)/2$. (This representation was obtained using the [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation)). Let us take $\rho = \rho_0 \otimes \rho_1$, where $\rho_i$ are two-dimensional matrices. From the statement in the paper, we would expect that this means $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho c^\dagger_0 c_1 ) = 0$. We have

$$ \mathrm{Tr} ( \rho c^\dagger_0 c_1 ) = \mathrm{Tr} \left[ (\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2 ) (\sigma^+ \otimes \mathbb{I})(\sigma^z \otimes \sigma^+)\right] \\
=\mathrm{Tr}\left( \rho_1 \sigma^+\sigma^z \otimes \rho_2 \sigma^+ \right) \\
 = -\mathrm{Tr} \left( \rho_1 \sigma^+ \right) \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_2 \sigma^+)$$

where I used the fact that $\sigma^+ \sigma^z = -\sigma^+$ and $\mathrm{Tr}(A \otimes B) = \mathrm{Tr}(A)\mathrm{Tr}(B)$. Now a general $2\times 2$ density matrix can be written as

$$ \rho_i = \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \beta^* & 1 - \alpha \end{pmatrix}$$

to ensure that $\rho_i = \rho_i^\dagger$ and $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_i) = 1$. Therefore, we have

$$ \mathrm{Tr}(\rho_1 \sigma^+) = \mathrm{Tr}\left[ \begin{pmatrix} \alpha & \beta \\ \beta^* & 1 - \alpha \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} 0 &1\\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right] = \mathrm{Tr}\begin{pmatrix} 0 & \alpha \\ 0 & \beta^* \end{pmatrix} = \beta^*$$

This is not zero in general. The same applies to $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho_2 \sigma^+)$,

### My question

I can't seem to show that if the state is written as $\rho = \rho_1 \otimes \rho_2$, then $\mathrm{Tr}(\rho c^\dagger_0 c_1 ) = 0$, as suggested by the paper. What have I done wrong?

Comment: Where does the paper claim that?

Comment: @NorbertSchuch Equations (23) and (24)

Comment: Are you sure the discussion is not restricted to the case of Gaussian states? There it is true without doubt. (The section of the paper discusses the XX model, which certainly has Gaussian ground & thermal states.) -- Beyond Gaussian, this might still hold due to some extremality of Gaussian states for a fixed covariance matrix (e.g. they extremalize the entropy), but I don't know on the spot.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch If I was to show this for a Gaussian state, what assumption would I have to make in my calculation above?

Comment: Gaussian states (with fixed particle number, which is the case for the XX model) are fully specified by the correlation matrix $\mathrm{tr}(\rho c_n c_m^\dagger)$.

Comment: As for your argument, I have only skimmed it, why do you *assume* tensor product form? This is the opposite direction of the argument!

Comment: I chose a tensor product form for the state because I assume the statement is an if and only if statement (?), so thought I’d test the converse

Comment: Compelling logic! -- In any case, the converse *is* true, because product states are uncorrelated and uncorrelated states don't have correlations. -- Nevertheless, the title of your question and your proof sketch have nothing to do with each other.

Comment: If I would have to make a guess, the issue is that you take the tensor product in the spin basis, while it should be in the fermionic basis (where, in fact, it is not really clear what a tensor product is). But I think you should first clarify your question.